# Is it possible to force one flexbox column not to grow beyond height of another column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, subject says it all.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r9aou8h/)

I want `column2` to have height of `column1` content's height and become scrollable for the rest of list.

It is possible with pure flexbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `display: flex` on your `container` but it's not necessary.

The trick is to set column 2 to `display: absolute`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.column2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
    Bla <br>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br>
    Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br>
    Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br>
    Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br>
    Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br>
    Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br> Bla 2 <br>
  </div>
</div>
```